# Kali 2020.1b no autoresizing to window with virtual manager

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, virt-manager

I am running ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a default KVM/QEMU/Virt-manager installation (as said on linuxconfig etc.). I have a fedora virtual machine which automatically resizes to fit the viewer window and a kali Linux machine which does not.

Both were installed by the virtual machine creator tool with virt-manager with default settings. I have enabled the resize to window settings in virtual manager preferences.
I have installed the spice vd agent in the guest.

How can I make kali auto-resize to the window as well? I mean resize and not scale.